# Solving $\frac{x+y}{xy}=2$, $\frac{x-y}{xy}=6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x+y}{xy}=2,\ \ \frac{x-y}{xy}=6$$

I am not understanding how to solve the equation. I tried dividing the whole equation by $xy$, but, that didn't work too. Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take the 1st eqn divide 2nd eqn then apply [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo). Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac 1y+\frac 1x=2\tag 1$$
$$\frac 1y-\frac 1x=6\tag 2$$
Now $(1)+(2)$ gives you
$$\frac 2y=8\Rightarrow y=\frac 14.$$

Answer (score 4):

We have a system of equations:

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=2$$
$$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}=6$$

From equation 1 we have,

$$y=\frac{x}{2x-1}$$

putting it in equation 2 we have,

$$x=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Putting $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ in $y=\frac{x}{2x-1}$, we get $y$ in terms of a compound fraction,

$$y=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{-\frac{2}{2}-1}$$

$$\implies y=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: You can verify them by putting them in **original equations** and see that whether they satisfies your system or not.  I have checked already so I would place a solution set, called **System's solution set**. $$S=(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4})$$

Answer (score 3):

- $x+y=2xy$
- $x-y=6xy$

so:

$x-y=6xy=3*2xy= 3(x+y)$

so

$2x=-4y$

and

$x=-2y$

By replacing above equation in the first equation, we have:

$-2y+y=2*(-2y)*y$

so

$y=4y^2$

and finally:

$y=1/4$ and $x=-1/2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\{^{\frac{x+y}{xy}=2}_ {\frac{x-y}{xy}=6}<=>$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{2}, y=\frac{1}{4}$$